# nginx: Bleeding off sessions when cookie affinity is used?

Tags: nginx

We use cookie affinity. Works fine.

When we want to bleed sessions off a server, (e.g. allow existing sessions to continue hitting a server, but not have any new sessions directed to that server), how do we do this?

And is it possible to monitor nginx to see how many sessions are on each server, so we can know when the server can be taken down?  (Or need we do this at the app level in our app?)